# Build iOS, Windows, C++ and Android in one place

Tags: android, ios, windows, jenkins, build

Currently we've setup a Jenkins Server on a Mac Mini to build our iOS SDK and Apps. Also our Android AARs and C++ Projects are build there.
Unfortunately we have also a Windows SDK, which we are building on an external Windows machine.
All this works kind of, but of course is not scalable (only if we buy better machines). Is there a possibility to build Windows in a Container or even better go to Google Cloud Build and do there everything in different Pipelines? Are there other alternatives out there?
Would be thankful for tipps!

Comment: Azure/Amazon pipelines is also an option for complete build coverage. what is your budget like? are you looking to do it as cheaply as possible or as comprehensive as possible with both CI/CD?

Comment: Budget shouldn't be such a big problem. The Problem is that i want my pipelines in one place. We currently have our whole build setup on a local mac mini and everything we use in the GCloud. Just wanted to know if there is a possibility to have to have windows and iOS (and everything i enumerated above) builds covered in Google Build or smth similar (could also be smth similar).

Comment: azure pipelines works pretty well with everything included - dev.azure.com you can build iphone,android and windows. i recommend azure since you're doing windows sdk stuff but amazon cloud works similarly(but requires just a bit more setup). you should check out the pricing on both. if you'd rather go open source jenkins integrates well with containers now so you could potentially have everything except the apple stuff on a beefy windows server deployment.